# Ayuda en pseudocodigo

Tags: pseudocódigo

En un vector llamado LETRAS de dimensión 20, permita al usuario introducir N caracteres
alfabéticos (‘a’,…,’z’), luego muestre cada carácter del vector y la frecuencia con la cual este carácter
aparece en el vector.
Ejemplo:
Supongamos que el usuario introduce en el vector LETRAS los siguientes caracteres alfabéticos
LETRAS
D E A P R E Y T D K E T D P E
Entonces, la solución que usted escriba para el problema deberá, después de capturar los caracteres en
el vector producir el siguiente reporte:
D Aparece 3 veces en el vector LETRAS
E Aparece 4 veces en el vector LETRAS
A Aparece 1 vez en el vector LETRAS
P Aparece 2 veces en el vector LETRAS
R Aparece 1 vez en el vector LETRAS
Y Aparece 1 vez en el vector LETRAS
T Aparece 2 veces en el vector LETRAS
K Aparece 1 vez en el vector LETRAS

lo unico que he hecho es agregarle un contador, lo estoy haciendo en pseint antes de pasarlo a c#

```
Escribir "digite una palabra";
leer palabra;

Para i<-1 Hasta 20 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    LETRAS[i] <- palabra;
Fin Para

Para i<-1 Hasta 20 con Paso 1 Hacer
    Si LETRAS[I]== "A" || LETRAS[I] == "a" Entonces
        a <- a + 1;
    Fin Si
Fin Para
```

donde "palabra" es un caracter y LETRAS es un vector

Comment: y cual es el problema?

Comment: @gbianchi no se plantear muy bien la solucion en pseudocodigo

Comment: ok, yo no conozco mucho ese lenguaje de pseudo, pero veo que solo estas recorriendo el vector de letras una sola vez, para la letra a... ese es tu problema no? por favor aclaralo bien en la pregunta.

Comment: Yo lo que haria seria algo como Para i<-1 Hasta 20 con Paso 1 Hacer
   ` Si LETRAS[I]== LETRAS[I+1] Entonces
        //agregar la letra a un arreglo SINO I++
    Fin Si`
Fin Para despues contar cuantas veces se repite la letra en ese arrglo

Comment: En pseudocódigo no lo se pero lo que tienes que hacer es, posicionarte en la primera letra y recorrer el vector contando las repeticiones y eliminas esa letra del vector ( todas repeticiones), una vez hayas hecho esto pasas a la siguiente letra y así hasta el final

Comment: @gbianchi no, el problema era que no me decia exactamente cuantas letras habia y era un proceso muy tedioso como lo tenia

Answer (score 1):

```
inicio
    Escribir "digite una palabra";
    leer palabra;
    declarar un contador=0;
    caracter = ""

    Para i<-1 Hasta longitud(palabra) Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Para k<-1 Hasta longitud(palabra) con Paso 1 Hacer
          caracter = palabra[i]
          si caracter == palabra[k] entonces
             contador++
          fin si
        fin para
        imprimir "El caracter ", (variable caracter), " aparece ", contador, " veces", nueva linea
          contador=0
    fin para
fin
```

Lo que hace en el primer ciclo es tomar la primer letra del arreglo, luego en el segundo ciclo compara lo restante del arreglo, si hay más letras iguales suma el caracter, luego de obtener la primera letra pasa a la segunda iteración del primer for, entonces y hace lo anteriormente dicho hasta leer el último caracter.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional en C#, es un simple windows form que contiene un boton, un textbox donde introduces la cadena y un listbox para mostrar resultados. Al dar click en el boton toma la el texto que esta en el textbox1 y muestra los resultados en el listbox.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string line = textBox1.Text;
            char caracter = ' ';
            int compt = 0;


            string checkd = "";

            for (int x = 0; x < line.Length; x++)
            {
                if (!checkd.Contains(line[x].ToString())) //Revisa si la letra ya ha sido contada
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < line.Length; y++)
                    {
                        caracter = line[x];
                        if (caracter == line[y])
                        {
                            compt++;
                        }
                    }
                    listBox1.Items.Add("El caracter " + caracter + " aparece" + compt + " veces");
                    compt = 0;

                    checkd += line[x].ToString(); // Almacena la letra contada
                }
            }
        }
```

Aqui una imagen ilustrativa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si notas cuenta los espacios en blanco tambien, espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: gracias viejo, estoy probandolo porque la forma en la que lo estaba intentando resolver no me servia y era muy tedioso

Comment: Si te sirve la respuesta marcala +1 para los nuevos usuarios puedan ver que la respuesta es util

Comment: ya le hice, **gracias** viejo, me sirvio bastante

Comment: @deibystevenperalta ¡En hora buena!

Answer (score 1):

PSeInt no puede reconocer una cadena de caracteres como un arreglo, pues en PSeInt cadena es solo un tipo de dato, por lo tanto este código no puede ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 1):

He estado explorando un poco PSeInt, y me parece un entorno muy interesante para comenzar con la programación.

El algoritmo que pides quedaría como aparece a continuación, en pseudocódigo de PSeInt (los índices de los vectores están basados en 1).

```
Algoritmo FrecuenciasCaracteres
    Dimension LETRAS[20];
    Dimension FREC[20];
    Definir N como Entero;
    Definir c Como Caracter;
    
    // Pedir los N caracteres al usuario
    N <- 5;
    Para i<- N hasta 1 Hacer
        Escribir "Introduzca una letra (quedan ", i, "): ";
        Leer c;
        LETRAS[(N - i) + 1] <- c;
    FinPara
    
    // Calcular las frecuencias
    Para i<-1 Hasta N Hacer
        FREC[i] <- 0;
        Para j<-1 Hasta N Hacer
            si LETRAS[j] = LETRAS[i] Entonces
                FREC[i] = FREC[i] + 1;
            FinSi
        FinPara
    FinPara
    
    // Visualizar los datos
    Para i<-1 hasta N Hacer
        Escribir "Letra #", i, " ", LETRAS[i], " aparece: ", FREC[i], " veces.";
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```

También se le podría pedir N al usuario.
Espero que te ayude.